# PIC18F97J60 program download problem

Tags: microcontroller, pic, microchip, pickit

I have a problem with downloading the .hex file to PIC18F97J60 using PICKit2. The software I'm using is MikroC when I'm trying to send the file it shows me:

> (warning: Some configuration words not in hex file. Ensure default values above right are acceptable)

Does anyone know how to tackle this issue, and what is the configuration needed?
I'm very sure about the pins connection for (VDD, VSS, ENVREG, VDDCORE/VCAP, and MCLR). This is the first time trying to program it.

Comment: You had to set the configuration Bits in your project..

Answer (score 0):

You had to set the configuration bits, but with mikroC you cannot set the configuration bits in your source code (like xc8 e.g.)
You had to set the bits in the edit Project window.

Comment: Do you have any idea which bits should be adjusted ? Because there is a lot. I made my research about it, I’m not sure if the bits that should be adjusted is relate to oscillator.

Comment: You have to had a look at all configuration bits. It depends on your application which are important. Have a look at the datasheet,